# Changing Sprite Spawns

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite

Here is my code that I m using below and i want it to spawn from the bottom of the x-axis in portrait mode right now in spawns from the top in portrait mode how do i edit the code to do this?

```
- (void)addBalloon {

        // Create sprite
        SKSpriteNode * monster = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"balloon"];

        // Determine where to spawn the monster along the X axis
        int minX = monster.size.width / 2;
        int maxX = self.frame.size.width - monster.size.width / 2;
        int rangeX = maxX - minX;
        int actualX = (arc4random_uniform(rangeX)) + minX;

        // Create the monster slightly off-screen along the top,
        // and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
        monster.position = CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height +  
 monster.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:monster];

        // Determine speed of the monster
        int minDuration = 2.0;
        int maxDuration = 4.0;
        int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
        int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

        // Create the actions
        SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX, -
monster.size.height/2) duration:actualDuration];
        SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        [monster runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking here. You want to spawn a sprite on the bottom of the **X**-axis?
In case it is what I think you are asking, you only have to switch:

```
monster.position = CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height + monster.size.height/2);
```

&&

```
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX, - monster.size.height/2) duration:actualDuration];
```

with:

```
monster.position = CGPointMake(actualX, - monster.size.height/2);
```

&&

```
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height + monster.size.height/2) duration:actualDuration];
```